# Horizontal scrollbar doesn't work

Tags: tcl, scrollbar, tk-toolkit

I am new to tcl/tk and I try to create an interface contains a textarea and two scrollbars (vertical and horizontal)
our problem is that I can see the horizontal scrollbar but it is not enabled

**code :**

```
frame .textarea 

label .textarea.l -text "Text"
text  .textarea.txt -width 70 -height 20 -xscroll {.textarea.h set} -yscroll {.textarea.v set}
scrollbar .textarea.v -orient vertical   -command {.textarea.txt yview}
scrollbar .textarea.h -orient horizontal -command {.textarea.txt xview}


grid .textarea.l -sticky nsew
grid .textarea.txt .textarea.v  -sticky nsew
grid .textarea.h        -sticky nsew

grid rowconfigure    .textarea  .textarea.txt -weight 1
grid columnconfigure .textarea  .textarea.txt -weight 1

pack .textarea -side left
```

**printScreen :**

[image]

Comment: Use the option -wrap none with the text widget.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin thank you

Answer (score 1):

The text widget will not make use of the horizontal scrollbar if it is set to wrap the lines in the text (which it does by default). To disable wrapping, use

```
text $path ... -wrap none ...
```

Documentation: [text](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm)

Comment: It'll _use_ the scrollbar, but the width of the scrollable area will default to the width of the viewable area, so the scrollbar should always be covering the range 0–100%. Embedded images and widgets can force things.